# Which is better and why to store web application logs , Application Insights or Azure table storage? Please suggest

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I want to store application exception logs, which option is better app insights or table storage.

Comment: Better how? In terms of costs, performance, query/analysis abilities, storage? You need to give more information if you do not want (future) questions closed and/or downvoted.

Comment: In terms of cost and performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the minimal amount of information you're providing:

Application Insights is the more mature solution. You get lots of stuff you would have to build yourself for Exception data in Table Storage. This includes stuff like reporting, trends, correlation, alerting and whatnot.

Have a look over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions.

The document is about a web application, but you can store information from all types of applications in Azure. For this, also see [TelemetryClient.TrackException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#trackexception)